# Row by row mapping keys of dictionary of dataframes to new dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have two dictionaries of data frames `LP3` and `ExeedenceDict`. The `ExeedenceDict` is a dictionary of 4 dataframes with keys `'two','ten','twentyfive','onehundred'`. The `LP3` dictionary has keys `'LP_DevilMalad', 'LP_Bloomington', 'LP_DevilEvans', 'LP_Deep', 'LP_Maple', 'LP_CubMaple', 'LP_Cottonwood', 'LP_Mill', 'LP_CubNrPreston'`

Edit: I am not sure of the most concise way to title this question but I think the title suites what I am asking.

There is a column in each dataframe within the `ExeedenceDict` that has row values equal to the keys in the `LP3` dictionary.

Below is a 'blank' dataframe for `two` in the `ExeedenceDict` that I created. Using the code:

```
ExeedenceDF = []
cols = ['Location','Size','Annual Exceedence', 'With Reg Skew','Without Reg Skew','5% Lower','95% Upper']
for i in range(5):
  i = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

  i['Location'] = LP_names
  i['Size'] = [39.8,24,34,29.7,21.2,53.7,61.7,27.6,31.6]
  ExeedenceDF.append(i)

ExeedenceDict = {'two':ExeedenceDF[0], 'ten':ExeedenceDF[1], 'twentyfive':ExeedenceDF[2], 'onehundred':ExeedenceDF[3]}
```

```
Location    Size    Annual Exceedence   With Reg Skew   Without Reg Skew    5% Lower    95% Upper
0   LP_DevilMalad   39.8    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   LP_Bloomington  24.0    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   LP_DevilEvans   34.0    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   LP_Deep         29.7    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   LP_Maple        21.2    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
5   LP_CubMaple     53.7    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
6   LP_Cottonwood   61.7    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
7   LP_Mill         27.6    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
8   LP_CubNrPreston 31.6    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Below is the dataframe for the key `LP_DevilMalad` in the `LP3` dictionary. This dictionary was built by reading in data from 10 excel spreadsheets. Using the code:

```
LP_names = ['LP_DevilMalad', 'LP_Bloomington', 'LP_DevilEvans', 'LP_Deep', 'LP_Maple', 'LP_CubMaple', 'LP_Cottonwood', 'LP_Mill', 'LP_CubNrPreston']
for i, df in enumerate(LP_Data):
  LP_Data[i] = LP_Data[i].dropna()
  LP_Data[i]['Annual Exceedence'] = 1 / LP_Data[i]['Annual Exceedence']
  LP_Data[i] = LP_Data[i].loc[LP_Data[i]['Annual Exceedence'].isin([2, 10, 25, 100])]


LP3 = {k:v for (k,v) in zip(LP_names, LP_Data)}
```

```
'LP_DevilMalad':     Annual Exceedence  With Reg Skew  Without Reg Skew  Log Variance of Est  \
 6                 2.0           21.4              22.4               0.0091   
 9                10.0           46.5              44.7               0.0119   
 10               25.0           60.2              54.6               0.0166   
 12              100.0           81.4              67.4               0.0270   
 
     5% Lower  95% Upper  
 6       14.1       31.2  
 9       32.1       85.7  
 10      40.6      136.2  
 12      51.3      250.6
```

I am having issues matching the column values of each dataframe within the dictionaries from the keys of `LP3` to the `Location` column in `ExeedenceDict` dataframes. With the goal of coming up with a script that would do all of this iteratively with some sort of dictionary comprehension.

The caveat is that the `two` dataframe is just the 6 index value in the `LP3` dataframes, `ten` is the 9th index value, 'twentyfive' is the 10th index value, and `onehundred` is the 12th index value.

The goale data frame for key `two` in `ExeedenceDict` based on the two data frames above would look something like this:

Noting that the rest of the dataframe would be filled with the values from the 6th index from the rest of the dataframe values within the `LP3` dictionary.

```
Location    Size    Annual Exceedence   With Reg Skew   Without Reg Skew    5% Lower    95% Upper
0   LP_DevilMalad   39.8    2   21.4    22.4    14.1    31.2
1   LP_Bloomington  24.0    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   LP_DevilEvans   34.0    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   LP_Deep         29.7    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   LP_Maple        21.2    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
5   LP_CubMaple     53.7    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
6   LP_Cottonwood   61.7    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
7   LP_Mill         27.6    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
8   LP_CubNrPreston 31.6    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it without a reproducible example, but I would do something along the lines:

```
index_map = {
    "two": 6,
    "ten": 9,
    "twentyfive": 10,
    "onehundred": 12
}

col_of_interest = ["Annual Exceedence", "With Reg Skew", "Without Reg Skew", "5% Lower", "95% Upper"]

for index_key, df in ExeedenceDict.items():
    lp_index = index_map[index_key]
    for lp_val in df['Location'].values:
        df.loc[df['Location'] == lp_val, col_of_interest] = LP3[lp_val].loc[lp_index, col_of_interest].values
```

Comment: I tried implementing the code and received an key error ```KeyError: "['Annual Exceedence'] not in index"```

Comment: Can't help you without a minimal reproducible example.  Are you sure there is an 'Annual Exceedence' column in each df? Maybe some typo in some of them... Try providing minimal data in your question

Comment: I amended the question to include how I created the two dictionaries. The data frame values from the `LP3` dictionary are read in from 10 different excel spreadsheets.

Comment: I was able to fix the key error so, no error comes up when implementing the code you provided however, `ExeedenceDict['two']` does not show any added values from before. All columns save for Location and Size are still NaN. Also, I did provide what one of the value data frames look like within the LP3 dictionary.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I noticed that a `.values` was missing after the LP3 df. I edited my answer.